# Why doesn't Java autobox int[] to Integer[]?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I have this method:

```
void stuff(Object[] array){
    // .. do stuff with the array
}
```

And trying to do this:

```
stuff(intArray);
```

It doesn't compile. I have to manually convert my `int[]` to an `Integer[]`.

Isn't autoboxing supposed to take care of this stuff for me? Why doesn't it?

Also since turns out the Java language doesn't do this natively, why isn't there a utility in the JDK to do this stuff? Isn't this why we have a standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

autoboxing doesn't work for array, autoboxing uses `static`  `valueOf()` method of wrapper class to convert primitive to its wrapper Object

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

Comment: Why not? Damn, Java has some annoying details..

Comment: @AvivCohn Java does autoboxing to convert primitive types to their wrapper classes.  An array is not a primitive type.

Comment: because it is designed to support wrapper class with primitive literal  value, and `int[]` is not a primitive literal

Comment: Aviv, just don't use Arrays, its bad anyway, use a list.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in my opinion. It just confirms that autoboxing doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @popovitsj _the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes_ `int[]` is not a primitive type.